# Postgres Indexes Need To Reindex

Tags: postgresql

I have a 300gb of data in one table. This table has a few indexes including the primary key i.e. duit_pkey.

Since there was a problem during backup, I had to drop all indexes and recreated it.

How can I reindex the primary key and all indexes fast. Now it takes me more than three hours to drop one index.

Comment: If you re-created all the indexes, there is no need to `reindex`. Dropping an index only takes a few milliseconds. If the `DROP INDEX` takes hours, it's waiting for an exclusive lock on the table.

Comment: Sorry I had to drop all other indexes except for the primary key index. How can I reindex the primary key index?

Comment: How do i check whether there is an exclusive lock on the table?